# Combine ASP.NET and ASP.NET core in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating a solution using ASP.NET Core 1.1 (SDK 1.0.4) and I require to use `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.

According to this Github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089) 
they are porting those APIs from the .Net Framework in the upcoming 1.2 version. However, I have seen that you can create an ASP.NET Core app targeting the full .Net Framework. I have follow some tutorials but all of them seem to be outdated (.Net Core 1.0 using project.json) and I have found no way to make it work.

In the same manner, I have seen some Github projects that seem to run ASP.NET Core and System.DirectoryServices namespace using something called DNX (like this [one](https://github.com/unosquare/passcore/blob/master/src/Unosquare.PassCore.Web/project.json) ). However, this project also fails in Visual Studio 2017.

Is there any real solution to have access to `System.DirectoryServices` on ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a hacky way to go about it, but I haven't explored this enough, yet. I have noticed that when you create an "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" project, it doesn't allow you to change the .NET framework version to anything but available .NET Core versions. You'll need to create an "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)" project in order to use the full framework.

If you've already got an existing project you're working on, the best thing I can recommend is to simply create a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)" project and migrate your existing code over to that. For the most part, it should just be copy-and-paste. Like I said, there might be some other way, that I just don't know, but you at least have that method.

FWIW, DNX was .NET Core, before it was ".NET Core". There was a somewhat similar setup where you could run DNX on full .NET or just the "core" .NET functionality. It doesn't really help you here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to target manually an ASP.NET Core Web Application to the full .NET Framework without success, and now it turns there is actually a project template to do just that!!! Thanks!!!